# While loops asking for correct imput

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, except

I'm new to python and I'm looking to code a small calculator for divisions, that includes while loops and if conditionals

My code looks like this:

```
a = input('first number')
while type(a)!=int:        
try:
    a=int(a)
    print('imput number is correct ',a)
except:
    print('Imput data is not correct ')    
    a=input('first number')
b = input('second number')
while type(b)!=int and b!=0:
    try:
        b=int(b)
        print('Imput data is correct',b)
    except:
        print(' imput data is not a number, please only imput numbers ')
        b=input('second number')
 while b==0:
    try:
        c=1/b
        print('imput number is correct ',b)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Cant divide by 0')
        b=input('second number again')
 if type(a)==int and type(b)==int and b!=0:
        c=a/b
        print('the result is: ',c)
```

The program suddenly ends after you imput 0 a second time in the second number space, but the proccess should keep asking for a value that is a number and different from 0

Answer (score 0):

After `b=input('second number again')` is executed, `b` is a string, so `b == 0` is `False`(a string is never equal to an integer).

Comment: but they do ```b=int(b)```

Comment: Apparently the code has some indent issue. I assumed that  `while b==0:` is on the same level with `while type(b)!=int and b!=0:`. If not so, there won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find this easier if you write a common function to get the user input. Something like this:

```
def get_input(prompt, nonZero=False):
    while True:
        try:
            if (n := int(input(prompt))) == 0 and nonZero:
                raise ValueError('Value must be non-zero')
            return n
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)

a = get_input('Input first number: ')
b = get_input('Input second number: ', True)

print(a/b)
```